# Join fields in script

Tags: elasticsearch

Our index has a join field (parent documents with many child items). We would like to make a search on child items, with a filter that sums a number from the parent document with a number from the child.
Is it possible to access parent fields in the filter script? If so, how can we do it? Would it need a recent version of ES?

We use ElasticSearch 6.6. We've tried playing with has_parent, inner_hits and script_fields, but we can't access informations from both parent and child in the same script.

Answer (score 0):

**Perform the search query on your child type and use `has_parent` to filter with parent fields**

```
GET data/ChildTypeName/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "has_parent": {
          "parent_type": "ParentTypeName",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "my_parent_field": "my_parent_field_value"
            }
          },
          "inner_hits" : {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: our problem is that we want to make a calculation between a parent field and a child field, and we can't have them both at the same time.